# JsessionID not sent as cookie

Tags: jmeter

I am developing a JMeter script for the export of xlsx file. As part of the script the header manager includes the following :

```
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Host: xxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxx.com
Referer: https://xxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxx.com/xxxxxxxx/
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

And on checking the Request Body in View Results Tree I found that the cookie data is sent in the following way :

```
X-CSRF-Token=xxxxx; JSESSIONID=xxxxx.xxxx; ROUTEID=.xxxx; JSESSIONIDSSO=xxxxx
```

Now I checked the same transaction manually. Here I observed that as part of Request Headers Cookie is sent the following way :

```
JSESSIONID=yyyyy.yyyy; X-CSRF-Token=xxxxx; JSESSIONID=xxxxx.xxxx; ajs_user_id=xxxxx; ajs_anonymous_id=xxxxx; style=default; ROUTEID=.xxxx; JSESSIONIDSSO=xxxxx
```

While running the JMeter script I received Response Code as 500. I believe that the reason for this could be that JSession ID (yyyyy.yyyy) is not sent in the script. I am not sure how to send this as I am not able to figure out any previous transaction in which this was generated. Note that this particular transaction is responsible for exporting the xlsx file. All the previous transactions and this transaction have all of the following details same :

```
X-CSRF-Token=xxxxx; JSESSIONID=xxxxx.xxxx; ajs_user_id=xxxxx; ajs_anonymous_id=xxxxx; style=default; ROUTEID=.xxxx; JSESSIONIDSSO=xxxxx
```

But only  JSESSIONID=yyyyy.yyyy used here is different from the previous transactions. How to send the JSession ID here.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that the cookie is not valid somehow (i.e. domain or path mismatch, expired, etc.).

JMeter's [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) checks cookies by default and stores only "valid" ones. If there is a problem with the cookie you can disable this check and see whether it resolves your problem. It can be done by adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
CookieManager.check.cookies=false
```

Additionally you can set the [cookies policy](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/params/CookiePolicy.html) to something less restricting like `netscape`

[image]

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-cookie-manager)

If the above hints don't help you can always extract the cookies values from the [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) response header using a suitable [JMeter Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and manually build [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) request header in the HTTP Header Manager.